# Problema a la hora de recuperar registros en la tabla

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, mariadb

Al abrir la pagina categoria.php que tiene el formulario para ser rellenado 
con los datos de la base de datos con el archivo categoria.js no me muestra 
absolutamente nada. Ya comprobé que tenga registros en mi tabla de la base 
de datos pero nada esta recuperando el formulario. Podrían ayudarme?

Este seria el archivo php donde esta el formulario a ser cargado.

**categoria.php**

```
 <?php 
 require 'header.php';

 ?> 

 <!--Contenido-->
   <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
   <div class="content-wrapper">

     <!-- Main content -->
     <section class="content">
         <div class="row">
           <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="box">
                 <div class="box-header with-border">
                      <h1 class="box-title">Categoria <button class="btn 
 btn-success" onclick="mostrarform(true)"><i class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i> 
 Agregar</button></h1>
                     <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                     </div>
                 </div>
                 <!-- /.box-header -->
                 <!-- centro -->
                 <div class="panel-body table-responsive" 
 id="listadoregistros">
                     <table id="tbllistado" class="table table-striped 
table- 
bordered table-condensed table-hover">
                       <thead>
                         <th>Opciones</th>
                         <th>Nombre</th>
                         <th>Descripcion</th>
                         <th>Estado</th>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                       </tbody>
                       <tfoot>
                         <th>Opciones</th>
                         <th>Nombre</th>
                         <th>Descripcion</th>
                         <th>Estado</th>
                       </tfoot>
                     </table>
                 </div>

                 <div class="panel-body" style="height: 400px;" 
 id="formularioregistros">
                     aqui va el form
                 </div>
                 <!--Fin centro -->
               </div><!-- /.box -->
           </div><!-- /.col -->
       </div><!-- /.row -->
   </section><!-- /.content -->

 </div><!-- /.content-wrapper -->
 <!--Fin-Contenido-->
 <?php 
 require 'footer.php';
 ?>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/categoria.js"></script>
```

Este seria el archivo js que deberia de cargar los datos en la tabla.

***categoria.js***

```
 var tabla;

 //Funcion que se ejecuta al inicio
 function init()
 {
     mostrarform(false);
     listar();
 }

 //Funcion Limpiar
 function limpiar()
 {
     $("#idcategoria").val("");
     $("#nombre").val("");
     $("#descripcion").val("");
 }

 //Funcion mostrar formulario
 function mostrarform(flag)
 {
     limpiar();
     if (flag) 
     {
         $("#listadoregistros").hide();
         $("#formularioregistros").show();
         $("#btnGuardar").prop("disable", false);

     }
     else
     {
         $("#listadoregistros").show();
         $("#formularioregistros").hide();
     }
 }

 //Funcion cancelarform
 function cancelarform()
 {
     limpiar();
     mostrarform(false);
 }

 //Funcion listar
 function listar()
 {
     tabla=$('#tbllistado').dataTable({
             "aProcessing": true,
             "aServerSide":true,
             dom: 'Bfrtip',
             buttons: [
                 'copyHtml5',
                 'excelHtml5',
                 'csvHtml5',
                 'pdf'
             ],
             "ajax":
             {
                 url: '../ajax/categoria.php?op=listar',
                 type : "get",
                 dataType : "json",
                 error: function(e)
                 {
                     console.log(e.responseText);
                 },
                 "bDestroy"=true,
                 "iDisplayLength": 5,
                 "order":[[ 0, "desc" ]]
             }
         }).DataTable();
 }

 init();
```

Aqui estaria la imagen donde deberia de aparcer los datos almacenados en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Dónde estás imprimiendo los datos? Veo que en ninguna parte de este código hay un ciclo for o foreach que haga el rol de imprimir los datos que traes de la base de datos

Comment: Mil disculpas, no puse en el código de lo que pertenecia al archivo js, ahora actualice el código para que veas.